# How do i install ubuntu onto a chrombook with out using crouton

Tags: chromebook

I am trying to install ubuntu onto a chrombook as the base operating system completely remove chrome and only have ubuntu not a duel os system like crouton offers. is their anyway to do this.

Comment: Which model of Chromebook?

Comment: [Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1468964/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-chromebook-google-pixelbook-2017) is a full installation instruction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DB Tech's [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AxsckwmRhfw) on how to remove ChromeOS and install Ubuntu from a USB drive looks like a pretty decent tutorial. In his video description, he types out each step:

> Step 1. Enable Developer mode
>
> Developer mode will wipe your Chromebook back to factory settings so
> make sure you back up any data not on your Google drive.
>
> With your Chromebook turned off hold down the ESC and Refresh While
> keeping them held down, press the power button once.
>
> Press Ctrl + D to bypass this screen.
>
> Press Enter at the next screen.
>
> On the next screen press Ctrl + D to bypass this message.
>
> You will see a timer counting down in the top right hand corner of the
> screen. The Chromebook will reboot and you’ll see the screen with the
> red exclamation mark.
>
> Developer mode is now enabled, power off the Chromebook.
>
> Step 2. Modify the Chromebooks BIOS
>
> By enabling developer mode, your Chromebook will always display the
> screen with the red exclamation mark on startup. Let’s now modify the
> BIOS to allow us to install Linux.
>
> Turn the Chromebook on and press Ctrl + D to bypass the screen with
> the red exclamation mark.
>
> Your Chromebook is reset to factory settings so you will need to go
> through the Chrome OS setup again.
>
> Press Ctrl + Alt + T to bring up a terminal window tab.
>
> Type shell and press Enter.
>
> Type this: cd;bash ˂(curl https://johnlewis.ie/flash_cb_fw.sh)
>
> ** You'll have to replace that angle bracket with the one on your keyboard. YouTube won't let me use an actual angle bracket after the
> "bash"
>
> Choose the option to Modify my Chromebook’s RW_LEGACY slot and follow
> the on-screen instructions.
>
> Step 3. Enable USB boot
>
> Pressing Ctrl + D at the screen with the red exclamation mark on
> startup will take you to your Chrome OS install but pressing Ctrl + L
> will take you to the BIOS screen to boot from your USB drive. Let’s
> turn on the Ctrl + L functionality next:
>
> Press Ctrl + D at the initial startup screen to load Chrome OS. Press
> Ctrl + Alt + F2 at the Chrome OS login screen.
>
> Login using the password chronos
>
> At the terminal prompt, type sudo crossystem dev_boot_usb=1
> dev_boot_legacy=1
>
> Power off the Chromebook by typing in sudo poweroff
>
> Now on startup, if you press Ctrl + L, you will get the BIOS screen
> instead of Chrome OS.
>
> Step 4. Install Linux
>
> At this stage most of the work is done and all that’s left is to
> install Linux:
>
> Plug in your USB drive into the USB port of your Chromebook.
>
> Plug in your live Linux USB into the other USB port.
>
> Power on the Chromebook and press Ctrl + L to get to the BIOS screen.
>
> Press ESC when prompted and you will see 3 drives: the USB drive, the
> live Linux USB drive (I am using Ubuntu) and the eMMC (the Chromebooks
> internal drive). Choose the live Linux USB drive.
>
> Choose the option Try Ubuntu without installing. When Linux loads make
> sure you can connect to the internet (I am using my trusty USB to
> Ethernet hub combo for a wired connection).
>
> Click on the Install Ubuntu 18.04 LTS icon and follow the on screen
> prompts until you get to Installation type.
>
> We want to leave the Chromebook’s internal drive untouched so choose
> the option to do something else so that we can manually setup the
> partitions for Ubuntu.
>
> Ignore all the mmc partitions and look for your USB drive, if you’re
> not sure, look at the size of the drive.
>
> Check your partitions are correct and continue the install.
>
> The rest of the install is a standard install so just follow the on
> screen prompts.
>
> Once finished, reboot, remove the live Linux USB and press Ctrl + L
> You now have Linux installed. Run the software updates to make sure
> you have the latest firmware, drivers and software.

---

Alternative of Step 2:
If you don't want to press `Ctrl + L` everytime you boot, install UEFI instead of enabling the RW_LEGACY BIOS mode.

To do that, open a terminal in Chrome OS, and enter the command `shell`.

Then, download and runt the script with

```
 cd; curl -LOk mrchromebox.tech/firmware-util.sh && sudo bash firmware-util.sh
```

Afterwards, follow the on-screen instructions to install UEFI. For details see the [webpage](https://mrchromebox.tech/#fwscript) of the script.